# 64 bit FP hardware with two 32 bit FP units

Tags: floating-point, gpu, hardware, fpga

When a GPU claims different performance for FP64 vs FP32, does it mean it has separate circuits for FP32 and FP64? Or is it combining FP32 units into FP64 units? 
I'm asking this because I'm wondering about the best way to implement FP units on an FPGA, in particular, I want to have both FP16 and FP32 capabilities.

Comment: In IEEE754, FP64 has more than twice as many mantissa bits as FP32 (which in turn has more than twice as many as FP16), and many operations don't scale linearly.  Implementing on an FPGA is going to be highly dependent on the macrofunction you use.  Oftentimes designers build blocks for the longest precision, and simply round in order to support shorter results.

Comment: Ben Voigt, so do you think GPUs have separate circuits for 64 and 32 FP ops?

Comment: No, I suspect the ones that are fast at FP64 have just FP64 circuits (and maybe turn off part of each in order to save power when working with FP32 data), and the ones that reuse the FP32 circuit instead have to break the FP64 data into more than two FP32-sized chunks each and feed them through the FP32 pipeline, then reassemble them, which causes FP64 performance to be much less than half of FP64.  There's virtually no benefit to having an FP32 circuit when you already paid (in die area) for FP64 circuits -- just use what you have and round off (and skip the last few iterations).

Comment: Ok, so you're fairly confident they don't combine FP32 units to do FP64 computation?

Comment: I think that FP32 units used on FP64 data would need multiple passes, not multiple units acting on a single piece of data.  When your data is as highly parallel as what a GPU works on, there's not much difference in the end.  On the other hand there are a lot of different architectures out there, perhaps some of them have a split mode to stop the carry and let an FP64 adder instead add two FP32 numbers at a time.  Problem is, as I already said, the fields in an FP64 are not each double those in an FP32 -- the proportions change.  (mantissa width changes more proportionally than exponent width)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Do you know why my question got downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote, but this question is a general hardware question which is off-topic here, so I will vote to close: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."